# query to convert 24 date format to 12 date format in hive

Tags: hive

I have demo table 
I want to create view ,This is my query

```
create view Demo_View as
select sms_sent_identifier,year(sms_sent_dt)  Year1,
case month(sms_sent_dt) 
 when 1 then 'Q1'
 when 2 then 'Q1'
 when 3 then 'Q1' 
 when 4 then 'Q2'
 when 5 then 'Q2'
 when 6 then 'Q2' 
 when 7 then 'Q3'
 when 8 then 'Q3'
 when 9 then 'Q3' 
 when 10 then 'Q4'
 when 11 then 'Q4'
 when 12 then 'Q4'
 end  Quarter1, 
Month(sms_sent_dt) Month1,
day(sms_sent_dt) Date1,
***hour(sms_sent_dt) Hour1,***
minute(sms_sent_dt) Minute1
 from subs_sms;
```

O/p it is giving date hour as eg 12,13 i want it in 12 format i.e 11 am ,12 am 
How should i do it

Comment: Take look at following links: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html & https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in simple way by using reminder a%b. If you divide by 12 you will get the 12 hour value. or the second approach will be changing the format in the date into yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss to yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss. I have given the example for first and second approach approach below.

Please try this for first approach:

```
create view Demo_View as
select sms_sent_identifier,year(sms_sent_dt)  Year1,
case month(sms_sent_dt) 
 when 1 then 'Q1'
 when 2 then 'Q1'
 when 3 then 'Q1' 
 when 4 then 'Q2'
 when 5 then 'Q2'
 when 6 then 'Q2' 
 when 7 then 'Q3'
 when 8 then 'Q3'
 when 9 then 'Q3' 
 when 10 then 'Q4'
 when 11 then 'Q4'
 when 12 then 'Q4'
 end  Quarter1, 
Month(sms_sent_dt) Month1,
day(sms_sent_dt) Date1,
(hour(sms_sent_dt)%12) Hour1,
minute(sms_sent_dt) Minute1
 from subs_sms;
```

This is second approach:

```
hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sms_sent_dt),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))
```

Comment: Thanks I will check and let u know

Comment: It is coming in 12 format but it's not coming am or pm

Comment: for AM/PM marker you will need 'aa' to be present as part of the format. for example : hour(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(sms_sent_dt),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa'))

for further details go to : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html